# Tracking an event during navigation

Tags: javascript, ajax

The scenario:

1. Auser is on a page in my website, and clicks on a button
2. Clicking on the button sends tracking information to my server, and also redirects the user to a second page on the website

The problem is that regardless of request type (AJAX GET/POST or even IMG), 40% of the tracking calls do not complete before the navigation starts, so I'm losing data.

I can think of a few possible solutions, each with their drawbacks, but was wondering if there are any additional options besides these that I can try out.

1. Use AJAX callback or force synchronicity to make sure the tracking is successful; drawback - bad user experience as request can take a long time or potentially even timeout, and the user will be "stuck" in the first screen as if nothing happened
2. Send the event on the receiving end (page that was navigated to); drawback - requires passing information between pages, which complicates the tracking mechanism
3. Sending the event from the server side; drawback - can cause consistency issues in my tracking, as requests will come from both the server and the client
4. Use a redirect, so that the user will navigate to a page with only tracking, then immediately redirected to the original target page (ad-server style); drawback - this is very intrusive to the process and to the user experience

Obviously, another solution is to invest enough in infrastructure and multi-zone support so that the network calls will be as fast as possible, but the pure cost of such a solution takes it off the table.

Are there any additional hacks or methods that can be employed to avoid data loss?

Comment: Can you show the code that does tracking ajax call and redirect? I experienced similar issues on Node.js reporting to logentry. The only solution was to let the ajax call start within one tick and the action that interrupts the session (redirect in your case) be in another tick. I.e. `setTimeout(doRedirect);`

Comment: The tracking itself is part of an SDK:
https://github.com/cooladata/cooladata-js/blob/master/src/main/web/js/cooladatatracker.js